# Why is installing Fiona taking too long and crashes at the end?

Tags: python, anaconda, geopandas, gdal, fiona

So I've been trying to install **geopandas** and I found out I have to install **GDAL** and **Fiona** first.
I installed GDL with the command `conda install -c conda-forge gdal`

Then I am trying to install Fiona but it seems to be taking way more than it should.
Here's the command I used to install Fiona: `conda install -c conda-forge fiona`

Comment: Just install geopandas into a clean environment. conda will install all dependencies including gdal and fiona. If you install these first, conda may have to downgrade their versions for compatibility.

Comment: also if you're really worried about install time, check out mamba - it's a faster version of conda with the same API. But definitely do what Robert Davy suggests - just run `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDavy I've tried this, but unfortunately it didn't work. That's why I searched and found out I have to download GDAL and Fiona first separately. GDAL installing was very easy but Fiona takes hours installing and then it seems like the installing was interrupted with no clear error. Just multiple messages all starting with "Examining conflict for ......."

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDelgado I appreciate it. I will try mamba hopefully it will run. But my issue here isn't about time. Long time is just a sign of something not going well. There are a lot of issues that anaconda tries to fix but seems it's unable to.

Comment: you only have to download and install the dependencies separately if using pip or installing from source. if you're getting conflicts, you're probably not installing into a clean environment. Try `conda env create -n geopandas-env -c conda-forge python=3.8 geopandas`. This should work if your conda distribution is up to date. If not, try `conda update -c conda-forge conda` and if that's broken try deleting your conda installation and reinstall.

Comment: This worked @MichaelDelgado Thanks! Just wanted to mention that create syntax doesn't have "env" anymore :)